# WiFi Dongle not working. TP-LINK WN723N

Tags: wifi, pi-zero

I'm trying to set up my RPi Zero.
I purchased a TP-LINK WN723N and downloaded the driver from the website, I was trying to follow the installation instructions but when I try the command `sudo make` this error shows:

```
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=armv6l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.34+/build M=/home/pi/Desktop/New  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.34+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1367: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

This dongle is V3.1.

I tried creating the folder build in the kernel folder but I got another error.

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Searching a bit I found out that the version from the driver is for a lower kernel version, it seems higher kernel can't compile drivers for lower kernels, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange Network.  As you are new here, may I suggest you take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) as it can help those new to SE to get to use it more effectively! I am surprised by `CROSS_COMPLILE=` in there - you are compiling on the RPi itself and I wouldn't expect anything "cross-compiling" related {building software on one type of hardware system to run on a different one such that the executable files produced usually cannot be executed on the building machine hardware itself.} Where did you get the source code?